# LinearProgress bar is taking over the entire prompt

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to implement the LinearProgress @materail-ui after a button is clicked to display a linear progress bar informing the user that the request is being processed. I'm having a tough time with CSS design with LinearProgress. Currently the LinearProgress is taking over the entire dialogPrompt.
[LinearProgress taking over the DialogPrompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LNrM.png)

Here is the LinearProgress call in the button in React

```
                 <Button
                    onClick={handleSign}
                    color="primary"
                    disabled={isAuthenticating}
                 >
                    Authenticate
                </Button>
                {isAuthenticating && (
                    <LinearProgress
                        color="primary"
                        className={classes.linearProgress}
                        />
                  )}
```

I'm not sure if my issue is with the CSS design and was wondering if anyone could help in CSS Design to keep the linearprogress bar on the bottom of the popup.

```
    linearProgress: {
    position: "initial",
    top: 0,
    width: "10%",
    height: "10%",
    opacity: 0.4,
    borderRadius: 4
},
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** The problem is where you are placing the LinearProgress component, put it as the first child of the Dialog (no CSS required):

```js
<Dialog ...>
        <LinearProgress color="primary" />
        <DialogTitle .../> 
          ...
</Dialog>
```

It should look like this:
[image]

**NL;PR:** You can take a look at this [pastebin](https://codesandbox.io/s/lineardeterminate-in-dialog-material-demo-vo2jh?file=/demo.js:1760-1952). click on the button "Open alert dialog" and a dialog prompt with linear progress will pop up.